# Converting string to a list of paramaters in BASH

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that launches another bash script and needs to pass multiple parameters (which may contain spaces).  In the launcher script I am defining the parameters as a single string, escaping any spaces as necessary.  However I can't seem to get the parameters passed properly.

Here is my test setup to replicate the problem I am having:

test.sh

```
  
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  echo "${1}"
  shift
done
```

launcher.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
args="arg1 arg2 arg\ 3 arg4"
./test.sh ${args}
```

Running test.sh directly from command line (./test.sh arg1 arg2 arg\ 3 arg4)

```
arg1
arg2
arg 3
arg4
```

Running launcher.sh

```
arg1
arg2
arg\
3
arg4
```

I've tried multiple variations of double quotes, read, IFS, etc, but I can't seem to get the results I am looking for.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't pass arguments as single string. Just pass it as multiple quoted separate arguments

Comment: This is just to demo the issue.  In the real launcher script the parameter string has a default value which I want the user to be able to override by doing a single read -p which is why I am storing the parameters as a single string.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [**5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A friendly tip

After reading your entire question it seems you're trying to re-invent the wheel.

You should have tried `read --help`. It explains how to split user input into an indexed array.

### Example

```sh
read -a args -p 'Input args: '
```

## Full code example

**test.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for sArg in "$@" ;do
   echo "$sArg"
done
```

**launcher.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -a args -p 'Input args: '
./test.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried using read -a based on other examples that I found but still couldn't get it to work.  It looks like I I didn't have the "${args[@]}" syntax correct after the read.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bash array or `xargs` in *launcher.sh*:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

args=(arg1 arg2 "arg 3" arg4)

./test.sh "${args[@]}"

echo =======================

args="arg1 arg2 arg\ 3 arg4"

echo $args | xargs ./test.sh
```

Execution:

```
$ ./launcher.sh 
arg1
arg2
arg 3
arg4
=======================
arg1
arg2
arg 3
arg4
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my actual script, args is being collected with a single read -p which returns a string.  That is why in this demo script I stored it as a string.  Is there anyway to cleanly convert the string into an array?

Comment: What about using xargs ? I am updating my answer...